# swap output the order of the digits

Tags: python

I have one code here

and need to change the order of the digits

```
import math

def sucet_cisel(number):
    bla: int = 0
    while number > 0:
        xyzpremenna = number % 10
        bla += xyzpremenna
        number = (number - xyzpremenna) / 10
    return bla

def digit_root(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("od čisla:"))
    m = int(input("do čisla:"))
    for i in range(1,m + 1):
        sucet: int = math.floor(sucet_cisel(n*i))
        t=(n*i)*(2)
        x=' ';
        

print(n,"*",i,"=",n*i,(x*4),"*2","=",t,sep='')
```

they need to add () to this code so that in each result where there are 4 numbers they are moved

therefore print (t) need this script to run at that number

t=(n*i)*(2)

and the result of this to turn into this code

```
val = list(str(i))
digit = val.pop(-3)
new = int(''.join(val+[digit]))

od čisla:2554
do čisla:4505
2554*4505=11505770    *2=23011540
23011540
23011405
```

the script stops at the number I enter where is the problem?

```
20*1=20    *2=40
20*2=40    *2=80
20*3=60    *2=120
20*4=80    *2=160
20*5=100    *2=200
20*6=120    *2=240
20*7=140    *2=280
20*8=160    *2=320
20*9=180    *2=360
20*10=200    *2=400
20*11=220    *2=440
20*12=240    *2=480
20*13=260    *2=520
20*14=280    *2=560
20*15=300    *2=600
20*16=320    *2=640
20*17=340    *2=680
20*18=360    *2=720
20*19=380    *2=760
20*20=400    *2=800
```

this makes a code if I give

```
     n = int (input ("from number:"))
     m = int (input ("to number:"))

n20
m20
```

however, if in this script there is i

```
val = list (page (s))
digit = val.pop (-3)
new = int (''. join (val + [digit]))
```

does it calculate only one result where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's rewrite your problem to "given a number of greater than 4 digits, I want that same number but with all permutations of the last 4 digits.

```
import itertools
def permute(number):
    val = str(number)
    prefix = val[:-4]
    for combo in itertools.permutations(val[-4:]):
        yield int(prefix+''.join(combo))

print(list(permute(12345678)))
```

Comment: and if I want it for all the results?           `print(t*(2),x*4,n,"*",i,"=",n*i,(x*4),"*2","=",t*(2),sep='')`

Comment: they only need one result the previous code worked well (but I would like to add there if the number is less than 3 and even greater than 5 so that nothing changes

the previous code stormed calculated only one result and the script stopped and did not count the others (as in the example above how I adjusted it here)

and for all the results

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer from Tim Roberts, but using slices and format strings.

```
n = 12345678
s = str(n)
x = int(f"{s[:-5]}{s[::-1][:4]}")
```

`s` is `'12345678'`, `s[:-5]` is `'1234'`, `s[::-1]` is `'87654321'`, and `s[::-1][:4]` is `'8765'`. Put it all together and `x` is `12348765`.

Comment: its code works (unfortunately only for one result)

Comment: So you need all permutations of the last four digits?

Comment: Yes correct that's exactly what they need

Comment: I enter the first number 1 and the second 20 and the script counts several results

and if there will be 1000+ then I want it to arrange different numbers @Chris

Comment: Then you specified the problem very poorly.  I never could have guessed you wanted ALL permutations of the 4 digits.  That's not hard to do, but that's definitely not what you said.

Comment: Then I suggest you investigate `itertools.permutations`. combine with the answers above and you should be able to get what you need.

Comment: @Chris original code counted the original code counts many results

I just want one

def digit_root (n):
     if n == 0: return 0
     return (n - 1)% 9 + 1

in this way I would write Digit_root to the print and the script would move all the results 4 long numbers   the code stops the cells i need all the results to move the last 4 digits if there are 4 digits with 3 and 5 not moving